# Handling big reactive forms in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to find a better approach to handle complex angular forms. 
The form is really big and I need to find an approach to reduce complexity.

Here is an example of form structure:

```
{
    "fieldA" : ...,
    "fieldB" : ...,
    "fieldC" : ...,
    "profile": {
        "username": ...,
        "email": ...,
        "firstName": ...,
        "lastName": ...,
        ...
    },
    "settings": {
        "enableEmailNotification": ...,
        "notificationsEmail": ..., // required when enableEmailNotification
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

There are cases when validators are changed on the fly, for example when `enableEmailNotification=true`, component will add `Required` validator to `notificationsEmail`

Here are researched options:

## Option #0 - Classic

[sample on github](https://github.com/nicumaxian/angular-7fwvil/tree/master/src/app/zero-method/form)

This approach uses one form and one component.

Pros:

- A lot of code, but very simple

Cons:

- All logic is in one place. For my case this component becomes too big and hard readable or maintainable
- UI also becomes big enough

## Option #1 - Passing FormGroup to subcomponent

[sample on github](https://github.com/nicumaxian/angular-7fwvil/tree/master/src/app/first-method)

This approach sends `formGroup` to inner components as `@Input()` property.

Pros:

- Reduces part of the view

Cons:

- Form creation and validation rules are still on the parent component
- Only view size is reduced
- Validation logic is created in root component, but display errors in sub-component

## Option #2 - Creating custom ControlValueAccessor

[sample on github](https://github.com/nicumaxian/angular-7fwvil/tree/master/src/app/second-method)

Based on a [this article](https://medium.com/@tarik.nzl/angular-2-custom-form-control-with-validation-json-input-2b4cf9bc2d73) we can create custom ControlValueAccessor which will return an object for a part of a form.

Pros:

- Splits form in multiple forms. Form can be splitten in smaller independent parts.

Cons:

- Keeping JS object for a form value. Doesn't look very good

Answer (score 5):

My strategy for large complex forms is to have a wrapper component and sub components. each sub component has it's own form service and the wrapper has a master form service with the sub form services injected, consider this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'form-wrapper',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="save()">
      <sub-form-a></sub-form-a>
      <sub-form-b></sub-form-b>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
    </form>
  `,
  providers: [MasterFormService, FormAService, FormBService]
})
export class FormWrapper {
  constructor(private formService: MasterFormService) { }
  save() {
    // whatever save actions here
  }
}

@Component({ // form b compoent is basically the same
  selector: 'sub-form-a',
  template: `
    ... whatever template belongs to form a ..
  `
})
export class FormAComponent {
  form: FormGroup
  constructor(private formService: FormAService) {
    this.form = this.formService.form;
    // form a specific actions
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class MasterFormService {
  form: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, formAService: FormAService, formBService: FormBService) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      groupA: this.formAService.form,
      groupB: this.formBService.form,
    });
  }
}

@Injectable() // formB service is basically the same
export class FormAService {
  form: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      .. whatever fields belong to form a ..
    });
  }
}
```

this method creates highly reusable sub forms and lets you modularize / isolate form logic and templates. I often find that sub forms typically belong in more than one place anyway, so it keeps my code very DRY. In your example in particular, you can easily reuse the settings form and profile form components elsewhere in your application. One or twice I've even nested this structure again for an extremely complex form.

The con is that the structure may appear complex but you get used to it quick.

Comment: Thanks. It looks interesting. I will give a try.

Comment: How will you inform sub-form-b about a change in sub-form-a e,g adding or removing a required validator based on values in sub-form-a

Answer (score 4):

Personally, for large complex forms, I'd like to keep the form logic in one component, so it's easy to chain the observables, but use a couple of Services as helpers. Both for initializing the form, and handling the actions (returning new form values, Validation, authorization, etc)

- The logic/tracking is in the `FormComponent`
- Initialization of the Form in is in the `FormInitService`
- Actions are handled in one pr multiple `FormActionService(s)`

**FormComponent**

```js
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private formActionService: FormActionService,
    private formInitService: FormInitService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.FormInitService.getForm();
    this._trackFieldA();
    this._trackProfile();
  }

  // Track a single field
  private _trackFieldA() {
    this.form.controls.fieldA.valueChanges.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b))
    ).subscribe(fieldA => {
      console.log('Field A Changed');
      this.formActionService.doSomething();
    });
  }

  // Track a group
  // Use ['controls'] for nested controls to skip typechecking errors
  private _trackProfile() {
    combineLatest(
      this.form.controls.profile['controls'].username.valueChanges,
      this.form.controls.profile['controls'].email.valueChanges,
    ).pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b))
    ).subscribe(profile => {
      console.log('Some profile field changed');
      this.formActionService.doSomething();
    });
  }
}
```

**FormInitService**

```js
export class FormInitService {
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  public getForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      fieldA: 'Some init value',
      fieldB: 'Some init value',
      profile: this.formBuilder.group({
        username: 'Some init value',
        email: 'Some init value',
        ...
      }),
      ...
    });
  }
}
```

**FormActionService**

```js
export class FormActionService {
  public doSomething(): any | void {
    console.log('Something')
  }
}
```

You still have quite some code in the FormComponent and template, but it's really easy to read and maintain. Splitting in multiple Components can often become very confusing, especially when working in teams, or when some (huge) refactor needs to be done.